# MySQL Left Join add doesn't exists rows to result

Tags: mysql

I have this two tables:

**Users**

```
uID | NAME |
1  | N1   |
2  | N2   |
```

**raports**

```
rID| TEXT | DATE       | USER
1 | awda | 2015-02-16 | 1
```

And I try to get all users with `raports.DATE = 2015-02-16` or users for which raport with this date doesn't exist.

I try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `raports` ON uid = user WHERE (usr_id in ('1', '2'))
```

Comment: When you write usr_id , do you mean uID??

Comment: also `uid = user` - aren't the field names case sensitive? In any case, `user` is a reserved word...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting all users with report date could be done as

```
select
u.*
from users u
join raports r on r.user = u.uID
where r.date = '2015-02-16'
```

Getting users who are not in that report date could be done as

```
select 
u.* from users u
left join raports r on r.user = u.uID and r.date = '2015-02-16'
where r.rID is null
```

Comment: will be its work when i will have raports for user1 and user 2 with different dates ? will this return me for date which i set for user1, user 1 and null for user2 ?

Comment: The first query only returns users with the date specified in where condition i.e. user1 as you mentioned. The 2nd query will return user2 since it will not have the date in raport.